# URL Rewriting on Hostinger.fr

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I ask your help because I would like to do soms URL rewritting. 
Here is the htacess file I wrote for my site

```
    # Do not remove this line or mod_rewrite rules and search engine friendly URLs will stop working
    RewriteBase /

    Options +FollowSymlinks
    Options -Indexes

    php_flag display_errors off

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^helper/?$ index.php?action=helper [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^probabilite/?$ index.php?action=proba [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^demon/?$ index.php?action=demon [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^info/([[:digit:]]+)$ index.php?action=info&competence=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

The host I use is hostinger.fr but I don't know how to use the rewriteRules on it.  (They said that it is activated and the first line (RewriteBase /) must be here)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have an actual question or problem?

Comment: I ask  if someone has used this host and have rewritted the url correctly. So I can take his example to make mine work ...

Comment: But you didn't give an example of what you are trying to accomplish so what good is someone else's code going to be if it doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: You see the htacces in quote ? I would like to rewrite urls. For example, urlOfmysite/helper (instead of urlOfmysite/index.php?action=helper . I ask if another lines  are required in order to make this work on hostinger.fr .

Comment: I see the code but my point is you have not stated what's broken. The code `looks` fine, so what's not working? That's what I'm getting at. What exactly is happening. The only thing I see right now is your `rewritebase` should come after the `RewriteEngine`.

Comment: on Wamp, I should have a path like that : /myFolder/helper . What about on hostinger  ? Thanks for your help

Comment: Whatever your document root is, is where the files will go. It's not really host specific. Hosting companies set up your server to use the main document root so your URL should just be `/helper`

Comment: Can you please explain what `([[:digit:]]+)` is? Surely that should simply be `(\d+)`?

Comment: OK. When I see on SSH console, I see a folder (public_html) when I can see the files of my site. That was what I find odd (and ask the path).

Comment: @Mike Rockett : It see that soms people  speaks which of the two (\d and [[:digit::]]) is the best. I use it Apache mod_rewrite compatibility.

Comment: @hp95 - You still have not clarified the **exact** problem you are having. Your code is fine (except for the position of `RewriteBase`, and you should probably use `(\d+)` instead of the other). If those two things are fixed, you shouldn't have a problem. `mod_rewrite` on any server is the same - it should just work. If you are getting an error, please tell us what it is. If you are not getting the desired result, what are you getting instead? Please be clear about your problem, otherwise we simply cannot help you.

Comment: Now, it works on localhost (but I must change the url in the <a href= ... ></a>). I will test on my site